# c# tibia OTClient Bot - need an advice

Tags: c#, memory-address

I'm writing a bot to game Tibia but it is at OTClient  + ASLR, so it changes addresses everytime we restart it, but i'm doing this to my own usuage -> I'm ready to find new addresses every time :)

I know how to use CheatEngine.. I find for address which is '104E8010'

Then I apply this code

```
public int GetInt32(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 address) { return BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadBytes(pHandle, new IntPtr(address), 4), 0); }

static double hpL = 0x104E8010;


 public int GetHealth(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 address) { return GetInt32(pHandle, address + (int)hpL); }
```

It results some weird numbers. I cant find any good tutorial online about how to read values from memory!
I'm using double value in Cheat Engine -> the address show is 100% good cuz it changes when im changing my hp value, but my struggle is how to use it in c#?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a look at the System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal class. It has methods for allocating, copying, and converting managed and unmanaged memory.